# I want to logout using button in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

```
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<form>
   <input type="button" id="logout" value="logout" name="logout">
</form>
```

I created the session during the time of login now i wanted to destroy it by using button. I don't want to go to `<a href="">logout</a>`, please tell me what to insert on my PHP code.

Comment: uh, if you destroy the session, then you will be logged out, since sessions are generally how logins are accomplished in the first place.

Comment: The question subject is vague, but I think you want to logout the user without going to any URL; take a look at ajax. You have  to handle the flow carefully tho, and make the UX good.

Comment: Would it have killed to have searched for "destroy session with a submit button php" on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your form to POST to a script that will destroy the session:

```
<form action="/logout.php">
 <input type="button" id="logout" value="logout" name="logout">
</form>
```

`/logout.php`

```
session_destroy();
echo "You have been logged out"
// (or redirect to the login page, etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

And in the `logout.php` file, you can:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header ("location: login.html");
?>
```

And this will log the user out by destroying all the session variables and redirecting to login page...

P.S. - you can decorate the button as you want and it will work as long as it redirects to `logout.php` file... **You really don't need a form for that, you can just use a button of any element that redirects to the logout file**.

Still, if you want to use a form you can:

```
<form action="logout.php">
 <input type="submit" id="logout" value="logout" name="logout">
</form>
```

Hope this helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply what you can do is, destroy all session cookies

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
// redirect here
```